# IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage:

Tags: asp.net, exception

I'm using Asp.Net Core 3.1 and thru Challenge method, calling an external endpoint to authenticate

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Challenge(string provider, string returnUrl,string userName)
        {
           
                var props = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)),
                    Items =
                    {
                        { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                        { "scheme", provider },
                    },
                    Parameters =
                    {
                        { OidcConstants.AuthorizeRequest.LoginHint, userName }
                    }
                };

                var result = Challenge(props, provider);
                return result;
            }
```

Error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', HttpResponseMessage.Content: 'System.String'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Have you managed to solve it @Mahendra?

Answer (score 6):

Got this exception when I created a new .NET 5 project in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

> IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from:
> 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage:
> 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', HttpResponseMessage.Content:
> 'System.String'.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
> address, CancellationToken cancel)
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(string
> address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
> cancel)

Before starting the app I got this error:

[image]

Required components - `dotnet msidentity tool`

You can fix this in Connected Services - Service dependencies and set up Microsoft identity platform by pressing Configure.

[image]

For me it got stuck like this and nothing happened though:

[image]

In `appsettings.json` I then found the following code:

```
/*
The following identity settings need to be configured
before the project can be successfully executed.
For more info see https://aka.ms/dotnet-template-ms-identity-platform 
*/
```

Visited https://aka.ms/dotnet-template-ms-identity-platform and used the tool `msidentity-app-sync` instead. Started of by installing it and then verifying I had the tool installed.

[image]

[image]

```
dotnet tool install -g msidentity-app-sync
dotnet tool list -g
```

Then ran `msidentity-app-sync` in the projects folder. A new `App registrations` will be created in `Azure Active Directory` and the project now works.

[image]

[image]

You can also specify tenant and client yourself if you wish to use an existing app like this:

```
msidentity-app-sync --tenant-id <tenant-id> --username <username> --client-id <client-id>
```

Comment: If you vote down please say why. Very hard to improve answers otherwise.

Comment: did not downvote, but: no damn chance to `dotnet tool install -g msidentity-app-sync` :/ every option they offer, I always get an 401..

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed also with Dusan's answer. From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/

Authority is the address of the token-issuing authentication server. The JWT bearer authentication middleware will use this URI to find and retrieve the public key that can be used to validate the token’s signature. It will also confirm that the iss parameter in the token matches this URI.

I am not using a public token-issuing auth server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30718671)

Comment: Just sharing what helped me buddy... might help someone else too... deleting this answer won't help anybody at all...

Comment: I had this when using an access token retrieved from Azure AD B2C. I can also confirm it was due to an incorrect Authority. For AD B2C the authority should be set to `https://<B2C tenant name>.b2clogin.com/<B2C tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/<user flow or policy name>/v2.0/`

Comment: @Poc275 This resolved my issue! This should be an accepted answer. I struggled too many hours with this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much this relates but someone may find it useful for dealing with this exception.

I am using Asp.Net Core 3.1, trying to implement JWT authentication. After setting Authority I began receiving similar [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXdsR.png).

[Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U15D3.png) of the issue was setting 'ValidIssuer' parameter, instead of setting Authority.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you: I used an scaffolded example from https://dev.to/moe23/asp-net-core-5-rest-api-authentication-with-jwt-step-by-step-140d

within this example the Nuget package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt was referenced.
I removed it, as I don't need it, and the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

We are able to resolve above issue by upgrading .NET Framework Runtime version from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2 in Web.Config file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem by config the authority wrong in API
I learning from a book. It guide me set the value https://tenant-id.auth0.com
But when create account in auth0. it add us to the url e.g.: https://tenant-id.us.auth0.com
[image]